# Calculate subtotal on quantity increment on single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm using the following code to calculate subtotal on quantity increment on single product page in WooCommerce. This works well

```php
/**
 * @snippet       Calculate Subtotal Based on Quantity - WooCommerce Single Product
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 4.1
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'bbloomer_product_price_recalculate' );
 
function bbloomer_product_price_recalculate() {
   global $product;
   echo '<div id="subtot" style="display:inline-block;">Total: <span></span></div>';
   $price = $product->get_price();
   $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
   wc_enqueue_js( "      
      $('[name=quantity]').on('input change', function() { 
         var qty = $(this).val();
         var price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
         var price_string = (price*qty).toFixed(2);
         $('#subtot > span').html('" . esc_js( $currency ) . "'+price_string);
      }).change();
   " );

}
```

I would like the calculated subtotal to appear/work only if WooCommerce product quantity (in the product page)- is more than 1, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `var qty = $( this ).val();` in an if condition. If greater than 1..

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    
    echo '<div id="subtot" style="display:inline-block;"><span></span></div>';
    
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    
    wc_enqueue_js( "      
        $( '[name=quantity]' ).on( 'input change', function() {
            var qty = $( this ).val();
            var price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
            var price_string = ( price*qty ).toFixed(2);
            
            // Greater than
            if ( qty > 1 ) {
                $( '#subtot > span').html( 'Total: " . esc_js( $currency ) . "' + price_string );
            } else {
                $( '#subtot > span').html( '' );                
            }
        }).change();
    " );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'bbloomer_product_price_recalculate' );
 
function bbloomer_product_price_recalculate() {
   global $product;

   if( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 1 ) {
        echo '<div id="subtot" style="display:inline-block;">Total: <span></span></div>';
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
        wc_enqueue_js( "      
        $('[name=quantity]').on('input change', function() { 
            var qty = $(this).val();
            var price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
            var price_string = (price*qty).toFixed(2);
            $('#subtot > span').html('" . esc_js( $currency ) . "'+price_string);
        }).change();
        " );
   }
}
```